# RealmResult dealing with time constraints

Tags: android, realm

How to modify realm result data when dealing with date and time? ASCENDING and DESCENDING is not enough for me.

Say for example I am getting a task thats within an hour of due?

```
 RealmResults<Task> tmp = realm.where(Task.class).findAll();
 for (final Task task : tmp) {
            String dateFormat = Utility.TIMEFORMAT;
            String current = "2:30:00 PM";
            Date currentTime = new Date(task.gettime());
            //currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(current);
                    if( isIncomingWithInHour(currentTime, calendar)){
                       realmresult.add(tmp) /// this result in error.
                    }
        }
```

As you can see ASCENDING and DESCENDING wont work in this kind of sorting. Anyway to give the reamlResult back to the adapter?  Realmresult has an onchangeListener and I want to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
RealmResults<Task> tmp = realm.where(Task.class).findAll();
```

You can do something like

```
RealmResults<Task> tasksInOneHour = realm.where(Task.class)
                                        .greaterThanOrEqualTo("time", startTime)
                                        .lowerThan("time", endTime)
                                        .findAll();
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Time constraints - while it is not clear in field of which type you store time in your Task class i'll provide an answer for a **long field** (and if it's not long, i suggest you to use it). Realm has a nice query picking capabilities, which we can make a use of:

   ```
   RealmResults <Task> tasksInOneHourList = 
   realm.where(Task.class).between("TIME_LONG_FIELD_NAME", CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_TIME + HOUR_IN_MILLIS).findAll();
   ```
2. Notify adapter - you can update adapter data as the following:

   ```
   tasksInOneHourList.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Task>>() {
       @Override
       public void onChange(RealmResults<Task> tasks) {
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   });
   ```